# iOS: Child View Controller in master of Split View Controller doesn't get viewWillAppear callback

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have created a sample app using XCodes' template for `Master-Detail` application. I am trying to add a `child view controller` to the `master` of the `Split View Controller`.

By following [Apple's guideline on View Controller containment](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) I have written the following setup:

```
func embedChildViewController(child: UIViewController) {    
    addChildViewController(child)
    child.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(child.view)
    child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)        
}
```

When running this on `iPad`, the view of `child` get successfully added to the view hierarchy and `viewDidLoad` of the child is called, however the `viewWillAppear` method is NOT. I can observe this behaviour only when using `Split View Controller` in this way.

When I add `child's view` as subview before calling `addChildViewController`, then everything works as expected - the view lifecycle callbacks are executed as expected.

```
func embedChildViewController(child: UIViewController) {    
    child.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(child.view)
    addChildViewController(child)
    child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)        
}
```

What am I missing here - why is the `viewWillAppear` method not called in the first example ?

EDIT:

Upon further investigation I've noticed that omitting the call to `addChildViewController(child)` causes the `viewWillAppear` of the child to be called ?

Comment: Check this out https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/. More precisely the part starting with "Why Is View Controller Containment Important?"

Comment: @Janna The way view controller containment is shown in this tutorial is just how I am using it as can be seen from the code sample in the question.

Comment: "By adding a view controller as a child view controller to a container view controller, the latter forwards messages related to appearance to its children. This is a key aspect of view controller containment. If the view of a child view controller is added to another view controller’s view without using the view controller containment APIs, the child view controller isn’t notified about events related to appearance. This means that messages such as viewDidAppear() and viewDidDisappear() are never sent to the child view controller, which could cripple the view controller."

Comment: @Janna I am still unsure as to which part of this I have to look at. I am calling the view controller containment API as the first step of the function in the question.